# Google Places autocomplete tap stops working on phones by Angular-Material

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, google-places-api, angular-material, mobile-website

There are multiple posts on SoF about tap not working on phones. e.g.:
[Cannot select from Google places autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333466/cannot-select-from-google-places-autocomplete)

None of the solutions worked for me. And I know, it's angular material to blame. Try these two simple pages ***on a phone***:

Not working (try tapping on suggestions):
https://my-rainy-tests-42.herokuapp.com/test1.html

Working:
https://my-rainy-tests-42.herokuapp.com/test2.html

The only difference between the two is that in the second one I removed the dependency on Angular Material.

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div style="position: relative; height: 100%">

    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);  // <--- remove ngMaterial and everything is fine!

    function initMap() {
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    }
</script>

<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyAFCOzkHUaXjZQYmbi55ovFCGHRsh9QoS0&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need it but the solution goes like this:

during app config, disable the click hijack, so angular material doesnt hijack your taps.

```
.config(function ($mdGestureProvider) {
      // For mobile devices without jQuery loaded, do not
      // intercept click events during the capture phase.
      $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
    })
```